# Can local vacuum disentanglement and emergent time offer a new interpretation for properties of particles, modelled as black holes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement

The notion that spacetime may emerge from entanglement between factors comprising a Hilbert space decomposition of the vacuum has been suggested by many (for example, M. Van Raamsdonk “Building up spacetime with quantum entanglement” Gen Relativ Gravit 42 (2010)).
It has also been proposed that time is an emergent property arising from Hilbert space factorization (for example, M. Noorbala “Spacetime from Hilbert space: Decomposition of Hilbert space as instances of time" arXiv:1609.01295v2 (September 2016)).
If the underlying geometry of baryonic matter is expressed as black holes, then local disentanglement of the vacuum may result. This suggests a local factorization of Hilbert space may apply, where some factors are orthogonal to the vacuum factorization. Such factors would support a separate time parameterization. From the perspective of the vacuum, propagation of fields hosted on these spaces would appear static. This suggests particle properties, such as charge and spin, actually arise from disentanglement.

Comment: What exactly is the thrust of the question? Are you asking if all of the steps can be made rigorous where one thing "suggests" the next or one thing "may" lead to the next?

Comment: Seems to me you want to discuss a non mainstream model details, as mainstream does not model particles as black holes.

Comment: Yes, the same assumptions are made here as in my previous question regarding the stress-energy tensor in GR, I.e. strong vacuum entanglement and particle models such as the Burinskii electron. Dark matter as black holes offer an interesting possibility: no entrained fields, so no emergent time, and consequently no apparent particle properties.